# How to change the gradient of polynomial?

Tags: polynomials

I have a polynomial equation:

$$y=(-2 \times 10^{-10} \times x^5)+(1 \times 10^{-7} \times x^4)-(2 \times 10^{-5} \times x^3)+(0.0018 \times x^2)-(0.0156 \times x)-0.164$$

I want to be able to change the equation of this line, so that when x=10, y=0.64.

Comment: Utterly incomprehensible.

Comment: Please rephrase your question and if possible give some background and motivation. As it stands, it's incomprehensible.

Comment: Does that help?

Comment: So you want to find a _different_ polynomial whose graph passes through the two given points? What should your new polynomial have in common with the existing one you quote?

Comment: It should be the same shape, just intersecting the specified point.

Comment: @TDJ92: What does "the same shape" mean here? Can you describe what would make the "shapes" of two polynomials different?

Comment: Nothing, it's literally moving the polynomial from (10,-0.15902) to (10,0.64). The shape should remain exactly the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a constant term to shift the polynomial up by $0.64 - (-0.15902) = 0.79902$.

In other words your $-0.164$ becomes $-0.164 + 0.79902 = 0.63502$.

That will do it, if I understand your question correctly now.

[See here](http://www.mathsisfun.com/sets/function-transformations.html) for an explanation of function transformations.